# noscript and disabling javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

According to developer.mozilla.org:

> The HTML `<noscript>` element defines a section of HTML to be inserted
>   if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is
>   currently turned off in the browser.

Most questions on Stackoverflow that relate to `<noscript>` are in connection with Javascript as script type.

If that is the case, the 'denial' of Javascript operation, hence the necessity of `<noscript>` would result from:

a) either the Javascript interpreter not being supported by the browser,

b) or the disabling of the Javascript interpreter through the browser preferences.

I can hardly imagine that today Javascript might not be supported by any browser.

So: **What reason can make a user disable the Javascript interpreter from within the browser?**

Comment: Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/why-do-people-disable-javascript and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8003323 and https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-block-JavaScript-from-their-web-browsers and https://www.google.com/search?q=why+do+people+disable+javascript I use Noscript myself, mainly to made it more difficult for third-party ads to load

Comment: @CertainPerformance — The first link (very interesting, indeed,) dates back to nearly nine years ago. Are the answers given really up-to-date?

Comment: The only semi-outdated point there that I see is platform support, which you essentially mentioned in your question - almost all browsers anyone cares about supports at *least* ES5 (which, of course, includes all basic Javascript). Other than that, the answer looks fine to me